# Saving HTML from WebView to existing file in Documents Directory

Tags: objective-c, webview, nsdocumentdirectory

I have been working on some code that loads and saves HTML files. I have been able to create them, but after they are edited in the WebView, I need to save an HTML file from the webView back to the documents directory. I am not sure how to create the HTML file however. I would appreciate your help. I have the document file path and title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can think of doing this is with javascript to pull out the html.  For example if you have a reference to your UIWebView object called webView the following would return a string containing the inner html:

```
[bodyView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.innerHTML"]);
```

You could then dress it back up to a complete html page, the javascript will only return the content within the `<body>` tags.  Presumably within your code that loads and then edits the html page you can know, and therefore store, any specific information that occurred outside of the `<body>` tags such that you can restore it?

Comment: Thanks. I used this in conjunction with writeToFile.